# Hide/Unhide-o-matic gives me error 400

Tags: android, web, google-play, google-play-games, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to use the Hide/Unhide-o-matic demo to hide a player from my game.
I've downloaded the simple app from here : https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools

I've placed my app my Client Id in the html file (something like that XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX), and again in the javascript file with the leaderbard id.

I can sign in, I can see the current leaderboard scores.
The problem appears when I pick a player and click the Hide button.
I'm getting this error :

`400: Invalid applicationId with value XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.`

I run this on localhost, but that shoudn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're signing in with an account that's listed in your "Testers" list?

If you're working on a published game, you'd be able to sign in and view a public leaderboard with any ol' account, but if you wanted to make one of the management calls (such as hiding a player), you'd need to be signed in with an account that you've listed in the "Testers" panel in the Games Services section of the Developer Console

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in as the owner, the only email address in the test section. The thing is, since I'm running it on localhost, the publication of the attached web application is denied. But this is ok, right ? I'm a tester.